# What is parent process of all the processes in iOS?

Tags: ios, process, operating-system

Just as in UNIX based system the **init** process is the parent of all the processes and similarly, the **zygote** process in Android OS has the sole purpose of launching other processes.

---

What is the name of the iOS equivalent process?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please delete. Consider posting on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Subjective questions are also allowed I guess. @rmaddy

Comment: It has nothing to do with being subjective or not. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. That's it. This question has nothing to do with programming so it should not be posted here. My first comment has a link of a better place to post it.

Comment: Apple has been very secretive about the internals of IOS. It is entirely possible that there is no such process. Or there might be one we have not been told about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the equivalent process on iOS and macOS is launchd.

It is run with PID 1 and it the parent of all other running user-space processes. The objective of launchd is similar to initd - having the responsibility of launching other processes during boot and various other phases of the system lifetime.

This is in thread with traditional Unix-based systems, where PID 1 is reserved for the process that is responsible for launching the user space part of the system. This was traditionally initd, but on modern systems that is often replaced with alternatives such as launchd (on macOS), systemd, upstart, and other init systems.